# How can we run multiple react -native apps in same physical device

Tags: android, react-native

We want execute two react-native applications in same android device ,therefore we started npm on two different port number as

(1) For first application we written at terminal as following command

npm start -- --port=8080

npm started for port 8080
[image: SS1]

(2) For second application we written at terminal as following command

npm start -- --port=8081

npm started for port 8081
[image: SS2]

then we had given following command for executing first application

Command : **react-native run-android**

we got following error

Application not registered error
[image: SS3]

Comment: This might be relevant: https://blog.expo.io/upcoming-limitations-to-ios-expo-client-8076d01aee1a

Comment: Question: How can Expo compile or run multiple projects at a time for same device?

Comment: @MuhammadHannan We are not using expo ,we used react native,npm for executing application.